# Initial velocity of particles in a 2D gravity simulation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, computational-physics, simulations, stellar-evolution

In $N$-body simulations of protostellar clouds (or similar objects), each particle is has a set of characteristics: mass, size, position, velocity, and (if the object is large enough or if we want to be really precise) a temperature profile (assume the composition of the particle doesn't matter). Mass, size (for collisions) and position are assigned at random since the distributions of the first two characteristics are unknown in real systems.

However, there are a few ways that the velocity vector could possibly be set initially; I am wondering which is would be the most accurate. Since velocity is the key to what shape the orbit will be, I figure this is the most important initial condition.

**1. Random Method**

Like mass, size and position, we randomly assign a velocity vector to each particle.

**2. Energy Theorem Method**

Given that the protostellar cloud has a temperature profile $T(\vec{r})$:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}m|\vec{v}|^2 = \dfrac{3}{2}kT(\vec{r}) \rightarrow |\vec{v}|(\vec{r}) = \sqrt{\dfrac{3kT(\vec{r})}{m}}$$

to which it can be expressed in vector form going radially as:

$$\vec{v}(\vec{r}) = \sqrt{\dfrac{3kT(\vec{r})}{m}}\langle\hat{r}, \hat{\theta}\rangle$$.

*So my question is:* In the long run, will either of these methods be advantageous over the other? Or will the system eventually settle down into a relatively stable configuration either way?

Comment: A gravitationally "bound" system never really "settles down". It will always keep ejecting some of the bodies until there is a final stable configuration of one or a few left. In practice, of course, you will probably not be able to simulate that long a timescale.

Comment: This might not apply to protostars, but if you're modeling the accretion disks around them, you also want to give them some average angular momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you randomly assign velocities independently of distance from centre of mass, the simulation will take much longer to settle down to a near-stable configuration.  The outer particles which are moving outward will have relatively high kinetic energy, so the configuration will expand further from the CoM, leading to weaker interactions and fewer collisions, requiring a much longer simulation time for anything interesting to 'evolve'.

If you assign a radial distribution of velocities which decreases with distance from the CoM, the outer particles which are moving outward have less kinetic energy, so the configuration will not expand so much.  This is far more likely to give you a compact configuration in which particle interactions are stronger and collisions more frequent, so the simulation evolves more rapidly.